# VB.Net Calling vb Sub/Function from a string/label?

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, string, function

In my VB code behind the aspx is it possible for me to call a function based upon a click on a string format.

e.g.

```
Sub testSub()
Do Nothing
End Sub

Dim test1 as string = string.format("hyperlink href blah blah", Hello)
Dim test2 as string = string.format("Call my test sub here?", World)
Dim stringtoUse as string = String.Format(test1, test2)
```

Then add my stringtoUse to my control. So that on my control I have two words Hello which when clicked goes to my hyperlink and World which when clicked calls my function/sub.

Any information or advice on how to approach this would be great.

Thanks Guys!

Comment: You definitely need two buttons.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your problem correctly, you want to be able to set the text from your code behind and have two different actions based on which half is clicked?

The most straightforward manner wold be to create two controls and set the text separately.

```
<asp:HyperLink id="hpMyLink" runat="Server" ...etc.  >
<asp:LinkButton id="lbMyLinkButton" runat="server" ..etc>
```

Then set the values from your page load (or wherever):

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
   hpMyLink.Text = string.format("hyperlink href blah blah", Hello)
   lbMyLinkButton.Text = string.format("Call my test sub here?", World)
End Sub
```

Then set your href for the first and handle the Click event for the second.

technically it would be possible to make a single link go two places, but it would require a great deal of trickery, would not work in some circumstances, and I can't imagine it would give you anything more than what you get from having two separate controls.

Comment: That wont work I dont think. Ive got a table and then a function that loops through all the cells in the table and depending on the outcome of my code it populates a cell in the table with my string format. Be it information or links with href in my string.format

Comment: It seems like you're reinventing binding, but given that additional information another option would be to output two a tags, one with the hyperlink for your hello tag and the other with an onclick. If you place a control on the page you could populate your second anchor's onlick with the output from a Page.GetPostBackEventReference() call. Google/Bing can supply you with examples and more info on that method.